# OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled doesn't return promised value

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, onesignal

After initialization OneSignal SDK my code trying to fetch user information with `OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled()`.

Sometimes it worked, but sometimes it doesn't return anything (*pending*).
The initialization code is fully copied from the official documentation.
Seems the OneSignal API doesn't answer that request. How it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The `OneSignal` variable initialized before SDK import.